# Spark : java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql://localhost/postgres

Tags: postgresql, apache-spark, jdbc

In my spark application, I am trying to connect to local Postgres database using following line:

```
val conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost/postgres", "postgres", "*Qwerty#")
```

Postgres server is running on port 5432 (default). I have also tried including the port.
I have also tried `Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver")` but it throws ClassNotFoundException. I have made sure that the driver is in the ClassPath.

I am running spark in the local mode.

But I am getting the above exception.

I have included the jdbc driver via `sbt` as mentioned here :
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql/42.2.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the problem was executors were not able to access the driver jar.

So passing driver jar using `spark.jars` configuration property solved it.

Its in the spark documentation [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html):

> Comma-separated list of jars to include on the driver and executor
>   classpaths. Globs are allowed.

Comment: can you please elaborate more? which jars? how exactly did you add them?

Answer (score 5):

You can also try out this code:

> Properties dbProperties = new Properties();
>
> dbProperties.put("driver", "org.postgresql.Driver");
>
> dbProperties.put("user", "postgres");
>
> dbProperties.put("password", "*Qwerty#");
>
> val conn =
>   DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgresDB",dbProperties);