# Problem connecting to mysql using Apache Spark

Tags: mysql, apache-spark

I installed Apache Spark on Windows and trying to connect to mysql database but I get the following error message.

> File
>   "C:\spark-2.3.2-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.7-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error
>   occurred while calling o33.jdbc. : java.sql.SQLException: No suitable
>   driver

Comment: you need to have mysql driver in classpath...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spark : java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql://localhost/postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50956547/spark-java-sql-sqlexception-no-suitable-driver-found-for-jdbcpostgresql-lo)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The infamous java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911253/the-infamous-java-sql-sqlexception-no-suitable-driver-found)